# What types of restrictions are in place to keep me from modifying built in types in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

If there are types that I want to modify to meet the project requirements, what type of restrictions are there for this?

By modifying I mean:

1. Finding the type you are interested that is closest to what you need.
2. Using the reflector to disassemble it.
3. Modifying it based on your own spec.
4. Using the new type (in another namespace) in your application.
5. Release your app as commercial or open source.

Is it totally OK to do this?

Comment: I'm curious: can you give examples of your requirements that would demand a modification to a BCL type?

Comment: For instance, if I were to have a BitArray that enumerates to bool without boxing/unboxing, I would have to either write it from scratch or modify it, which doesn't seem ok, so only #1 is ok.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from studying how they implemented BitArray, though.

Comment: I don't think it would be too hard to implement it from scratch anyway...

Comment: Do you really have a requirement that is basically "Make sure that there is no boxing/unboxing in `BitArray`?"  `BitArray` is pretty efficient in the storing of bools as integers and I didn't really see any boxing/unboxing going on in there.  Also, wouldn't that basically be a variation of `List<bool>`?

Comment: No that's the end goal. The boxing of a bitarray is explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213997/type-safe-bitarray-in-net

Basically if I can get away without boxing/unboxing when every ms counts (game), then I would rather do that.

Comment: I still don't see how the existing classes don't work for that case. Either using a `bool[]`, `List<bool>`, or a `for` loop over `BitArray` (not the `foreach` as discussed in that thread) should give as good performance as you might get out of it.  Sorry if I am being dense, but I just don't see your need to rewrite it.  I think you might need to explain it to me a bit more.

Comment: But do you think a List would be more efficient for billions of elements? I haven't compared yet, but I thought a bitarray might be more efficient in this case where only indexes are important.

Comment: I think the `for` loop over the `BitArray` (using its indexer) should be the best option, but I have not tested it.  Why not write some simple tests and see?  (Btw, I did see the boxing/unboxing in the iterator, which would give you a huge performance penalty indeed)

Comment: Yeah that's what I will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, *very* definitely not. Even if you *can* do it, it would violate the .NET framework licence. Whether you'd *actually* be in legal hot water would depend on your country probably, but you'd definitely want to consult a lawyer.

If you're intending on copying the functionality into a *new* type, then you'd probably have to bring in a load of other internal types and potentially other oddities. Just how much Microsoft code do you want to have to copy? Then you've got problems if the original type is updated in a new release, etc...

Just don't do it - ask a separate question for how to work around whatever deficiency you've run into, but don't start taking the framework code and putting a modified version into your own code base.

---

EDIT: I originally thought Joan was talking about modifying the code, rebuilding, and then *replacing* the BCL class in the framework. Here were my thoughts on that idea...

It's a really bad idea for technical reasons though:

- You wouldn't be able to sign the assembly properly again, meaning that at best you could only run apps under full trust (which I don't *think* checks assembly signatures).
- How would you deploy your new type? You'd quite possibly have to deploy it "over the top" of the real one, which would affect anyone else using .NET.

BCL types just aren't designed to be replaced like this.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Does it matter if my new type is in a new namespace? That's what I meant, will edit. If not, then what about giving the type a new name?

Comment: You're still on *very* dodgy legal (and ethical) ground. Really, it's a non-starter I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah the internal types would be a problem. What I was actually trying to say was, getting as much code from the existing type and severe/replace the internal dependencies. But like you say it might not make sense I think.

Comment: @Downvoter: Was the downvote due to the bit about replacing the type within the framework? If so, that was due to misreading the question... I've edited it out. If not, please explain where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Hey Jon, I get worried when you get a DV because of my question. I up voted in any case.

Comment: @Jon that stuff was still good information - I don't see a need to remove it.

Comment: Any naming issues etc don't matter. Taking others code, and using it as a basis for yours, counts as a "derived work". Rights to produce derived works are reserved for the copyright holder. He can give them to you, perhaps on some conditions (e.g. GPL does that), but there's nothing like that for .NET GCL, so by producing such a derived work, you'd be infringing on Microsoft copyright, with all the consequences this entails.

Comment: @Rex: I'll put it back in an edit, but separately to make it clear that wasn't Joan's intent. @Joan: I think I can live with losing 2 points of rep - don't beat yourself up over it :)

Comment: 2 points here, 2 points there, and soon Marc is going to pass you. Of course, if that happens, the universe may implode...

Answer (score 7):

That is not OK. The code you extracted using Reflector is copyrighted by Microsoft and some portions may even be patented. Either way, you cannot redistribute someone else's code as your own without explicit permission.

What you *can* do is re-create your own implementation from scratch. Describing what a class, object, or pattern *does* is not copyrighted (though it could feasibly, but not usually, be patented). You can describe what a string class, for example, should do, and write your own from scratch which also does that.

Legal implications aside, I am having trouble imagining a scenario where this would be a good idea from a technical perspective. If you step back and re-frame your problem in terms of the original thing you need to accomplish, you can probably come up with a much better solution. Or better yet, post *that* problem on Stackoverflow and get a lot more brains on it.

Answer (score 5):

Using Reflector to look at the BCL source code is technically [already breaking the license agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378498/can-i-reflector-the-net-base-class-libraries-bcl/378509#378509). I know everybody (myself included) does it, but you're already on shaky ground by point 2.

You can get around this by [viewing the original source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx), but this is licensed under the [Microsoft Reference Source license](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/referencesourcelicensing.aspx) which does not permit using the source code in modified form.

So no, this is not OK, I'm afraid.

Comment: Btw do you know why MS doesn't want ppl to look at their code from reflector, but not obfuscate it?

Comment: @Joan - They don't mind people looking at the code (as can be seen from the link to download most of the framework source) but the .NET Framework inherits its license agreement from the Windows operating system on which it is installed, which leads to the odd situation where looking at the original source code is legal, but looking at the source from a decompiled binary is illegal! I guess it's just one of those things...

Answer (score 4):

Not a lawyer but I'm going to say the answer is almost certainly No.  Disassembling a closed source project and re-releasing it sounds wrong.  Before doing this you must look at the licensing restrictions on the original binary.  But then again, not a lawyer.

A better way to approach this would be to look at projects which distribute their source freely.  For example Mono.  They clone much of the BCL and distribute the source as well.  It is perfectly legal to redistribute their source according to the license rules they use.  I won't speak to the conditions on the redistrubition of their source (not familiar with them) but I'm sure someone else on this thread is.

Comment: So, overall Mono guys are cool with their source distributed? That sounds good at least.

Comment: @Joan, Yes.  According to their wikipedia page, the different parts of Mono are released under different licenses, but they are all some variation of an open source license (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)).  But once again, I'm not a lawyer so don't bank on my opinion.